# Magento - Database transfer

Tags: magento

My magento store recently started showing a lot of errors due to accidently deleting some tables from the database (name: `magento`) so I reinstalled a fresh copy, created a new database (name: `magento_new`) and imported a recent backup. Now my website is up and working fine.

The data in this new database (name: `magento_new`) is around one month old and I have some orders which are in the database (name: `magento`).

My question is do you guys ever experienced this situation?
How do I import only orders from the database (name: `magento`) to the database (name: `magento_new`)?

Any information is greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Azeem

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you need to reinstall magento by pointing to old DB . Please try this at your local server then upload it at live.
Please follow the below step hope this will helps you. 
1. Download new magento version OR the version you have which you want to install 
2. Import live database to your local db (The DB which messed up) 3. Try to to install new magento by pointing to the old DB which is messed up. Means when you will go for installing magnto then it will prompt to put DB credentials.Then you need to put old DB details which is in your local sever. 4. it can take few mints or if your live site much lower version then it can take more than an hour. 5. When it will be done then you need to migrate only the files from local and community folder as well as frontend design and admin design file. Keep in mind we aleady have migrated DB. Hope this will helps you . thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All the information related to the orders is stored in the tables beginning with "sales_". You could try to import all those tables but some foreign keys might fall.

Orders are connected to the customers & products. If some customers or products do not exist in your old backup, the foreign keys will fail, thus the import will not succeed. This means you will have to import the customers first.

All the customer data is in the tables beginning with "customer_". But the same issue might appear.

Beside that, if new orders/customers were created in the meantime, you will have duplicate primary keys.

Conclusion: You can restore your old data by creating a very fancy SQL but there is no easy way to accomplish this.

Be sure to backup your database before trying anything! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are modules that can export/import orders and other information, and a few features in Magento by default.  The list is pretty long but I think that would be far easier than trying to use a custom made script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete all the info from the new magento_new database so you have a clean database and use this command.

```
SELECT * FROM [OLD_DATABASE].dbo.[TABLE]
  INTO [NEW_DATABASE].dbo.[TABLE]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all your orders in new copy of magento then please keep in mind two things.

1.Orders are associated with the products so you need to get all the SKU's which are associated with orders.

2.The order address, item details are stored in different tables.

Order Details : sales_flat_order

Order Item details(Products) : sales_flat_order_item

Order address details: sales_flat_order_address

like wise for products

catalog_product_entity - information about product entities.

catalog_product_entity_datetime - Values of product attributes with the datatype “datetime”.

catalog_product_entity_decimal - Values of product attributes with a floating point number content.

catalog_product_entity_int - Values of product attributes with the datatype “integer”.

catalog_product_entity_text - Values of product attributes with the datatype “text” (unlimited string).

catalog_product_entity_varchar - Values of product attributes with the datatype “varchar” (limited string, maximum 255 characters).

catalog_product_entity_tier_price - Values of product tier prices. The datatype is a floating point number.

You need to export all these tables.

ORELSE you can try once with the previous magento (old one)
1.Delete the local.xml file
2.Run magento and again install magneto.

What will happen here is it will again reinstall your complete tables and then you can have a clear idea which table got deleted previously.